# How to set value of a column of installation object of parse in android

Tags: android, parse-platform

I'm trying to learn how to use parse and at this moment I want to know how I can set the value of a column at initialization ("Installation" object).

This is my onCreate method.

```
    public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    Parse.initialize(this, "****", "****");
    ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();
    ParsePush.subscribeInBackground("", new SaveCallback() {
        @Override
        public void done(ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                Log.d("com.parse.push", "successfully subscribed to the broadcast channel.");
            } else {
                Log.e("com.parse.push", "failed to subscribe for push", e);
            }
        }
    });

}
```

I added a column called MacID. Whenever someone downloads the app, I want to get their mac address and save it to parse object. Thank you

Comment: Is the push notifications code not completely unrelated?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the installation object
First go to the parse website and create the required column in the installation class.

Then in code

```
    ParseInstallation installation = ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation();
                 installation.put("column name",mcIdValue);
                 installation.saveInBackground();
```